# SimpleXML namespaced attributes and value is empty?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following type of XML structure:

```
<catalog xmlns="http://www.namespace.com">
    <product product-id="test-product">
        <page-attributes>
            <page-title xml:lang="en">test</page-title>
            <page-title xml:lang="de">test2</page-title>
        </page-attributes>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

I used the following to fetch the product and it's `page-title` elements:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns', $xml->getNamespaces()[""]);
$xpath = '//ns:product[@product-id="test-product"]';
$product = $xml->xpath($xpath)[0];

foreach ($product->{'page-attributes'}->{'page-title'} as $title) {
    var_dump($title);
    var_dump($title->{"@attributes"});
    var_dump($title->attributes());
}
```

But I just get:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) {
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (0) {
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (0) {
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (0) {
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) {
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) {
}
```

How do I get the values of the `page-title` elements (`test`,`test2`)? Also how do I get the attributes? The attributes have `xml:` in front of them. Does that mean just the attributes are in their own namespace?

Comment: Cast them to a string (which is how you always have to get them from SimpleXML): `echo (string)$title;` inside the `foreach` loop...  Everything else you have should work.  `SimpleXMLElement` implements `__toString()`, but `var_dump()` won't respect that and it will always just look like you're getting more `SimpleXMLElement` objects back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things are wrong with your code:

- As @MichaelBerkowski mentioned, you need to convert an `SimpleXMLElement` to `string` if you attempt to retrieve it's value.
- You need to specify the namespace `xml:` if you attempt to retrieve the values of the `lang` attributes.

Your code should look like this:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns', $xml->getNamespaces()[""]);

$xpath = '//ns:product[@product-id="test-product"]';
$product = $xml->xpath($xpath)[0];

foreach ($product->{'page-attributes'}->{'page-title'} as $title) {
    var_dump((string) $title);
    var_dump((string) $title->attributes('xml', TRUE)['lang']);
}
```

Output:

```
string(4) "test"
string(2) "en"
string(5) "test2"
string(2) "de"
```

---

About the string conversion. Note that if you would attempt to do the following:

```
echo "Title: $title";
```

you won't have to explicitly convert to `string` since a `SimpleXMLElement` supports the `__toString()` method and PHP will convert it automatically to a string - in a such a string context.

`var_dump()` cannot assume a string context and therefore it outputs the "real" type of the variable: `SimpleXMLElement`.

Comment: Ah thank you that makes sense now. When do I use the `{"@attributes"}` nomenclature? I've seen that and I'm not sure when that applies.

Comment: PHP allows to access object properties like `$obj->{"PROPERTYNAME"}`. (true for every kind of object). The `SimpleXMLElement` has a property (literally) called `@attributes`, which is again a `SimpleXMLElement`.

Comment: Can you not reference namespaced attributes via `@attributes`?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible.